# RecyclerView setVisibility gone for image

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have one layout file with all my text and images. I want to leave blank some of the text and images but also remove the space it takes up from the layout file. So I used setVisibility and used TextUtils.isEmpty to remove text if its blank(" ")

I am not sure how to remove the image space. Can I use ic_launcher everytime I dont want image and just if it matches ic_launcher setVisibility(GONE)

```
public class BasicAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BasicAdapter.ViewHolder> {

List<AdapterData> mItems;

public BasicAdapter() {
    super();
    mItems = new ArrayList<>();
    AdapterData data = new AdapterData();
    data.setText("dummy text");
    data.setImage(R.drawable.image_one);
    mItems.add(data);

    data = new AdapterData();
    data.setText("");
    data.setImage(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    mItems.add(data);

    data = new AdapterData();
    data.setText("");
    data.setImage(R.drawable.image_two);
    mItems.add(data);

    data = new AdapterData();
    data.setText("dummy text");
    data.setImage(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    mItems.add(data);

    data = new AdapterData();
    data.setText("dummy text");
    data.setImage(R.drawable.image_three);
    mItems.add(data);




}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.test2, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    AdapterData data = mItems.get(i);
    viewHolder.text.setText(data.getText());
    viewHolder.image.setImageResource(data.getImage());




    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(data.getText())){
        viewHolder.text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else{
        viewHolder.text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }





}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return mItems.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


    public TextView text;
    public ImageView image;




    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        text = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        image = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


    }
}
}
```

Comment: im not sure what you trying to do, but why not setting image background to null or 0 when you want to remove image instead of setting def image?

Comment: refer this http://amolsawant88.blogspot.in/2015/08/easy-way-to-highlight-selected-rowitem.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to hide the image when it is ic_launcher you could do that (suppposing that data.getImage() returns the id of the drawable as integer):

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
  AdapterData data = mItems.get(i);
  viewHolder.text.setText(data.getText());
  viewHolder.image.setImageResource(data.getImage());


  if(TextUtils.isEmpty(data.getText())){
    viewHolder.text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }else{
    viewHolder.text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  }

  if(data.getImage()==R.drawable.ic_launcher){
    viewHolder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }else{
    viewHolder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  }
```

}

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks alot excatly what I needed